# React вывод изображения в зависимости от стейта

Tags: javascript, reactjs

в компоненту поступает проп с названием изображения

Изображений больше 80 000

Как правильно импортировать нужное мне изображение для вывода в компоненте?

Просто указав ссылку не работает

Answer (score 0):

Передавай не проп с названием, а проп с самим изображением

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-spence-9b6bc2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Так у меня много изображений, я не могу их все испортировать, у меня ./assets/27b4a6a65503eea71ff6607f5a6dc219.png

27b4a6a65503eea71ff6607f5a6dc219.png - должно быть переменной

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено. Переменную передаем в функцию require, и изображение импортируется в компоненту.

```
let img = '02b88d2293e0912af6b320a14c01cd37be96ac77_medium.jpg'
return <img src={require(path+img)} />
```

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: Это ответ, переменную передаем в функцию require, и изображение импортируется в компоненту

Comment: Переместил в ответ эти слова. Так надо отвечать в дальнейшем, пожалуйста, чтобы всем понятно было. Это же база знаний.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо